# How do I vertically align this image inside the header?

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the image, i have a logo inside the header (the blue part is the header), and i can't align it to be vertically at the center. I've put a border to the image just to see its size.[image: My page]

Basically all the CSS code behind the logo and header is this:

```
header{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: blue;
}

#logo{
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: you should also add some markup just so we can make sure that the CSS solutions work well with your specific markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using display [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox):

```
header{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

if you need help you can call me in the comments

Answer (score 0):

It may work in your case :

```
#logo {
    margin-top: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: auto !important;
}
```

as guys guys said , another way is using flexbox and and setting center value to align-items property. (add it in your header)

Or use align-self propery in your logo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </div>
</header>

<style>
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px; /* set the height of the header */
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```